# Load an array of JSON objects into R as a data.frame

Tags: python, json, r, pandas

I have an array of JSON objects as a string that I would like to load into R as a `data.frame`. IN particular, assume I have the following JSON,

```
[
  { "a": 1, "b": "c" },
  { "a": 1, "b": "d" }
]
```

What I want is a `data.frame` whose columns are all unique keys of all objects in the above, and 1 row per entry in the array, like so,

```
  a  b
1 1 "c"
2 1 "d"
```

This behavior is identical to `pandas.DataFrame.from_records` in Python. Does such a method exist?

Comment: `rjson` and `RJSONIO` seem to convert JSON objects to lists. I'm not sure how to go the extra mile to convert them into `data.frame`s.

Comment: `as.data.frame` probably, though be aware that data frames are required to have columns of equal length.